# Change a whole line in a .csv file

Tags: shell, csv

I want to create a shell script that changes a whole line according to input that user gives. I have a contacts.csv file that includes First Name,Last Name,Phone Number

For example a random contact

```
John,Doe,2103485922
```

So I want user to type the Last Name of a contact then script deletes the whole line that contains his last name and then insert a whole new line with new data.

For example, I want the above contact to be deleted if user types Doe (Last Name) in the input and then type a new contact. For example Sylvester,Stallone,1414246551.

Any clue?

I have tried this but it doesn't work like I want to:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Tell Me The Contact you want to delete"
read name | grep -evx $name >> contacts.csv  
echo "Please type a valid first name Press Enter,Last Name Press Enter and 
Phone number"
read fname
read lname 
read phone 
[[ $fname =~ ^[[:upper:]][a-z]+$ ]] || exit 1;
[[ $lname =~ ^[[:upper:]][a-z]+$ ]] || exit 2; 
[[ $phone =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]      || exit 3;
echo "$fname,$lname,$phone" >> contacts.csv
```

Comment: How does it not work the way you want it to? What happens? What do you think should happen?

Comment: I just cant find the correct command to remove the whole line

Comment: Please [edit] your question with example input, expected output, and actual output from your script. Currently, we have to guess all that from reading the script, but as you say, it doesn't work yet.

Comment: If you want to remove a line from a file, you could use `sed`.  Pipe the file through sed with `/$name/d`.  From what you've written above it looks like you're just going to append all of the non-matching lines back into contacts.csv.  To actually delete, you'd need to overwrite the existing file.  `sed` has an option to edit 'in-place'.  See `man sed`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question focuses on the ability to delete a line from the input file.  Probably the most straightforward approach is with `sed -i`.

For example:

```
$ cat test.csv
one,two,three
four,five,six
seven,eight,nine
$ name=five
$ sed -i -e "/,${name},/d" test.csv
$ cat test.csv
one,two,three
seven,eight,nine
$
```

I hope this helps.  Of course you ought to think about what happens if multiple last names match.  But I think this answers your immediate question about how to delete a line from a file given a pattern.

Good luck!